# Unable to run Activity from non activity class

Tags: android, class, android-activity, android-workmanager

I am  trying to run an Activity from Worker Class.

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

private final Context context;

public MyWorker(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Intent i1 = new Intent (context, DDBMain.class);
                    i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(i1);
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();

    return Result.SUCCESS;
}
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
E/WorkerWrapper: Trouble instantiating com.simran.powermanagement.MyWorker
java.lang.InstantiationException: 
java.lang.Class<com.simran.powermanagement.MyWorker> has no zero argument 
constructor
```

Comment: That's a problem with your Worker. You need a zero-argument constructor or one that takes `Context` and `WorkerParameters`.

Comment: public Worker (Context context, WorkerParameters workerParams). I found this in the documentation. Could you give me an example for clarification ?

Comment: Modify your constructor and call its super.

Comment: I am trying to do this but it is giving me an error:                                      
 public MyWorker(Context context, int x) {
        super(context, x);
    }

Comment: I'ts not an integer. It's WorkerParameters...

Comment: The problem was that i was using -alpha08 instead of -alpha09. This solved the constructor issue of 'cannot resolve WorkerParameters' but when i try to rebuild project. I get this error:                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                 
Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

Comment: Did u got the solution still ?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues with your code.

Switch to the new constructor which takes in a `Context` and `WorkerParameters` and call `super(context, params)`.

If all you need is a `context` there is already a `getApplicationContext` API on the `Worker`.

Comment: I used WorkManager 1.0.0alpha09 to solve this issue and i got an error and after excluding the source of error. I got alot more errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at the [WorkManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) and at the available [WorkManager codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0)

In this particular case, you may try something like:

```
public class MyWorker() extends Worker {

    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context appCtx, @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(appCtx, params);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), DDBMain.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();

        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Using the `getApplicationContext()` method available in the `Worker` base class, to access the application context. It's then a good idea to use the new constructor syntax introduced in WorkManager 1.0.0-alpha09 as the older one is deprecated and will be removed in the future.